# VBA Error: Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add a loop if formula for a single cell range called "Analysis" in sheet1. Depends on how many facilities report user selects, the "Analysis" cell will show the name of the facility not credible if the amount is less than 400k or unit less than 50. Each facility table has exactly 28 rows, and the "Analysis" range is 3 rows above the first table. I want to show all the facilities that are not credible using a loop formula.

The code used:

```
termfaccnt = Me.lstTermFacilitiesSelected.ListCount
sheet1.Range("Analysis").FormulaR1C1 = Analysis(Me.lstTermFacilitiesSelected.ListCount)

Public Function Analysis(TermFacCnt As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim FormulaStr As String

    FormulaStr = "=if R[30]C < 500000 or R[16]C[-2] < 500 then R[3]C[-2] & ""- Not Credible."" ELSE end"
    
    For i = 2 To TermFacCnt
        FormulaStr = FormulaStr & "if R[" & 28 * i + 2 & "]C < 400000 or R[" & 28 * i - 12 & "]C[-2] < 50 then R[" & 28 * i - 25 & "]C[-2] & ""- Not Credible."" ELSE end"
    Next i
    
    Analysis = FormulaStr 
End Function
```

If facility 1 and 3 are not credible, I would like to see if formula to yield "Facility 1 - not credible. Facility 3 - not credible." in Analysis range in sheet1. But I got an error of Application-defined or object-defined error pointing at the sheet1.Range("Analysis").FormulaR1C1 = Analysis(Me.lstTermFacilitiesSelected.ListCount).

Comment: An `IF`-formula has the syntax `=IF(condition, true-result, false-result)`

Comment: The OR condition should be `OR(R[30]C<50000, R[16]C[-2]<500)`

Comment: Updated the if formula and OR, and added & in front of second if. Error is gone. Thanks.